# Pthread on an ARMv8 device: 32-bit binary runs fine but 64-bit binary aborts. Any specific reasons?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, armv8

I am testing a small code which involves creating a thread on my ARMv8 device.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *fun(void *arg)
{
    sleep(2);
    printf("%s: Exiting now\n", __func__);
    pthread_exit(0);
    //return 0;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t th;
    pthread_create(&th, NULL, fun, NULL);

    sleep(3);

    printf("%s: Wait over\n", __func__);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code into a 32-bit executable and run it on the device, it seems to run fine.

```
fun: Exiting now
main: Wait over
```

But when I build it into 64-bit executable, I get the following output:

```
fun: Exiting now
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As far as I know, ARMv8 is completely backward-compatible. But here, the 32-bit binary runs while 64-bit binary hangs up.

Apart from that, while trying out things, I found when I change the fun() to:

```
void *fun(void *arg)
{
    sleep(2);
    printf("%s: Exiting now\n", __func__);
    //pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries run fine.

I looked into this article:
[Pthread: Why people bother using pthread_exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751017/pthread-why-people-bother-using-pthread-exit) and didn't get much information as to where the problem might be.

Here is some more information about my device:

```
Linux Version: Linux version 4.4.67 (lnxbuild@ecbld-bd213-lnx) (gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT
Total Memory : 3721056
```

So here are my questions:

1. Can there be any reason why the 32-bit binary runs while the 64-bit crashes on an ARMv8 device?
2. How does this error fix when I replace `pthread_exit(0)` with `return 0`?
3. Is there anything else that I might be missing here?

Minor Update:

I have tried changing the wait times and making various combinations of `pthread_join()`, `pthread_detach()` and `pthread_exit()` at all possible places, but to no avail. This is the simplest version I could provide.

Comment: How about reading the man-page of ptherad_create and which parameter types it takes? Your code invokes undefined behaviour **on both platforms**. Why do you ignore compiler warnings?

Comment: If you mean to say to make `void *fun()` as `void *fun(void *arg)`, then that didn't work. Can you please point out if I missed anything else?

Comment: In C, `void *fun()` is not the same thing as `void *fun(void*)`. The former is bad and obsolete practice.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Initially I had been trying with `void *fun(void*)`. But since it was not helping, I might have accidentally removed it at some stage during debugging. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you check device logcat? It surely contains some detail about crash. If you need to analyze found report - see [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash)

Comment: You should fire up `gdb`, and provide more information about the core dump, like the offending function, its parameters, and possibly a disassembly. ARMv8 is kind of tricky at the moment. Things are still maturing. For the longest time, GDB did not really work under Debian, so it made it difficult to debug issues.

Comment: @EOF Please read the question carefully before downvoting:
_I have tried changing the wait times and making various combinations of pthread_join(), pthread_detach() and pthread_exit() at all possible places, but to no avail. This is the simplest version I could provide._

Comment: @SimplyOm How is this *possibly* simpler than just replacing the `sleep()` in `main()` with `pthread_join(th, NULL)`?

Comment: I just meant I had tried using `pthread_join()`. Since the worker thread is aborting as soon as it reached the `pthread_exit()` line, it doesn't really matter if there is a `pthread_join()` or `sleep(3)` waiting in the main() thread. That is why I removed it. Besides, this discussion is not helping. So I'll stop.